# Error after adding hibernate-search-orm in pom.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, hibernate-search

After adding hibernate-search-orm in pom.xml file I am facing 2 issues.

### Issue 1:

Getting below notification in application.properties
[image]

### Issue 2:

Getting this compile-time error at the end of all error message

```
....defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>rokomari</groupId>
<artifactId>publisherinventory</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>PublisherInventory</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1209.jre7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If I replace below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

with this one

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

then no compile-error shows up.

Question 1: How can I solve the Issue 1?

Question 2: What is the difference between hibernate-search-orm and hibernate-search-engine?

Question 3: Please advice me to solve the compile-error issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue 1: Solved

Forgot to put spring.jpa.properties at the beginning.

Here is the complete one.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /var/lucene/indexes
```

### Issue 2: Solved

Well, just replacing the version of hibernate-search-orm from 5.5.4.Final to 4.5.1.Final solved the issue.

The final dependency is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```